# HSV colour space and Image histogram function

Tags: image-processing

I have plant colour image that contains plant, pot and soil. I tried to segment just the green leaves of plant by using hsv colour space then take the image histogram of each space but I dont know how can I benefit from image histogram function in Matlab. Can any one help me please?

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun and until you get a Matlab answer, you can do this with ImageMagick which is free and installed on most Linux distros and downloadable for OSX and Windows.

Let's start with a tomato plant in a pot with some soil:

[image]

Now use ImageMagick `convert` to remove (i.e. make transparent) all non-green pixels:

```
convert plant.jpg -fill black -fuzz 15% +opaque rgb\(128,170,100\) -transparent black out.png
```

So now it looks like this:

[image]

Now, if you want a histogram, run this command to generate a histogram and then sort by the most frequently occurring colour:

```
convert out.png -format "%c" histogram:info: | sort -rn | more
  91278: (  0,  0,  0,  0) #00000000 none
     18: (128,169,103,255) #80A967 srgba(128,169,103,1)
     16: (126,167,101,255) #7EA765 srgba(126,167,101,1)
     16: (125,166,100,255) #7DA664 srgba(125,166,100,1)
     15: (121,162, 94,255) #79A25E srgba(121,162,94,1)
     14: (124,165, 99,255) #7CA563 srgba(124,165,99,1)
     14: (122,163, 97,255) #7AA361 srgba(122,163,97,1)
     13: (120,161, 93,255) #78A15D srgba(120,161,93,1)
     12: (130,171,105,255) #82AB69 srgba(130,171,105,1)
     12: (129,170,104,255) #81AA68 srgba(129,170,104,1)
```

The first line shows the (unwanted) transparent pixels (see the final zero), and then the next most commonly occurring colour is RGB(128,169,103) with 18 pixels that colour.

Comment: Thank you Mark for the Magic solution, but can I install this program in window 7 and what is the Official website for that program?
zainab

Comment: Yes, you can install it on just about any OS and use it from the commandline or from C, Perl, PHP, Ruby and so on... http://www.imagemagick.org

Comment: The `sort` command I used is part of the GNU utils which can also be installed on Windows to make it more like a proper computer :-) http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net

Comment: I installed the program in my computer, I follow all the instructions in the download site and I have visual studio 2010 professional but the program dose not work.
If I used Matlab in my algorithm programing do you think this program will be useful for my application?
thank you
Zainab

Comment: You must probably go into Control Panel->System and set up your PATH environment variable so that the directory where ImageMagick is installed is at the start of your PATH.

Comment: Even if you use Matlab, ImageMagick is absolutely invaluable to anyone doing image processing.